# Screen Scroll in a game

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to get my game to scroll as a player along the y axis and the x axis.

Currently the coordinate systems of the window is out. :(

I am using the following line in openGl to scroll:

```
float tempX=px1;
float tempY=py1;
double left = tempX-screenWidth/2;
double right = screenWidth/2+tempX;
double bottom = tempY - screenWidth/2 + 300;
double top = screenHeight/2+tempY+ 300;
//gluOrtho2D(0,screenWidth,0,screenHeight);   (before scroll screen)
gluOrtho2D( left,  right, bottom ,  top);
```

px1 and py1 relate to my player and are updated as the player moves.
Currently if you get the window and resize it while the game is running you can see the images resize and my code is wrong as a square is displayed as a rectangle.

Comment: Do you want everything to scale up when the window resizes, or show more of the same-sized map?

Comment: To show more of the same sized map so I can go to the right to see the rest of the map and jump on platforms so the screen goes up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <map>
using namespace std;

size_t win_w = 0;
size_t win_h = 0;

void Box( int xoff, int yoff, int size = 10 )
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f( xoff + -1*size, yoff + -1*size);
        glVertex2f( xoff +  1*size, yoff + -1*size);
        glVertex2f( xoff +  1*size, yoff +  1*size);
        glVertex2f( xoff + -1*size, yoff +  1*size);
    glEnd();    
}

map< int, bool > key_map;

void keyboard( int key, int x, int y )
{
    key_map[key] = true;
}

void keyboard_up( int key, int x, int y )
{
    key_map[key] = false;
}


void display(void)
{
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    static int center_x = 0;
    static int center_y = 0;
    if( key_map[GLUT_KEY_LEFT]  ) center_x--;
    if( key_map[GLUT_KEY_RIGHT] ) center_x++;
    if( key_map[GLUT_KEY_DOWN]  ) center_y--;
    if( key_map[GLUT_KEY_UP]    ) center_y++;

    double left   = center_x - win_w/2.0;
    double right  = center_x + win_w/2.0;
    double bottom = center_y - win_h/2.0;
    double top    = center_y + win_h/2.0;

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, -10, 10);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glColor3ub(255,0,0);
    Box( 10, 10 );

    glColor3ub(0,255,0);
    Box( 100, 100 );

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    win_w = w;
    win_h = h;
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE);

    glutInitWindowSize(200,200);
    glutCreateWindow("Scroll");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutSpecialFunc( keyboard );
    glutSpecialUpFunc( keyboard_up );

    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how is this answer diffrent from what i seid? i just didn't write the whole code! :)

Comment: My god how I love these unicorns. It's hard not voting people up just to see them again!

Comment: Great example to start to work and to understand this kind of effect. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

i guess the problem is with the viewport resolution, i mean when you resize your window your viewport stays the same as before so you are still drawing in for example 640x480 screen while showing what you draw in a 800x600 resolution, so i think you have to call `glViewPort(0,0,screenWidth,screenHeight)` after any window resize event.

Comment: glOrtho( tempX - screenWidth/2, tempX + screenWidth/2, tempY - screenHeight/2, tempY + screenHeight/2, -1, 1 ); //maybe this would work?

Comment: so are you sure you are updating screenWidth and screenHeight? and `glveiwPort` isn't something to call every frame, you just have to call it whenever you get window resize event from windows